# MATLAB: Returning variables from programmatic GUIs

Tags: matlab, user-interface, variables

I have been trying to program a GUI which is supposed to receive one variable as an input and perform several operations that generate another variable.
The GUI will have one pushbutton that closes the GUI.

I am not (and don't want) to use GUIDE.

Below, I provide a minimal working example of a GUI that simply adds one to the input variable. The "Done" push button closes the GUI but **I cannot find out a way to export the variable to the workspace**.

```
% Is this the correct way to initialize the function for what I am trying to do?
function outputVariable = exampleGUI(inputVariable) 

    % Initialize main figure
    hdl.mainfig = figure();

    % Add Button
    hdl.addPushButton = uicontrol(hdl.mainfig, 'Units', 'normalized',
                                  'Position', [0.05 0.6 0.3 0.25], 'String',
                                  'Add One', 'Callback', @addOne);
    % Done Button
    hdl.donePushButton = uicontrol(hdl.mainfig, 'Units', 'normalized',
                                   'Position', [0.65 0.6 0.3 0.25], 'String',
                                   'Done', 'Callback', @done);
    % Static text
    hdl.sliceNoText = uicontrol(hdl.mainfig, 'Style', 'text',
                                'Fontsize', 16, 'Units', 'normalized', 
                                'Position', [0.35 0.2 0.3 0.25]);

    function addOne(~, ~, ~)
        inputVariable = inputVariable + 1; % add one to the current inputVariable
        set(hdl.sliceNoText, 'String', num2str(inputVariable)); % change static text
        newVariable = inputVariable; % new variable to be exported
    end

    function done(~, ~, ~)   
        delete(hdl.mainfig); % close GUI
    end

end
```

I would like to do something like:

In the workspace:

```
outputVariable = exampleGUI(inputVariable)
```

And after adding one to the input variable a certain number of times, I would push the "Done" pushbutton and the GUI would be closed and the workspace would contain both inputVariable and the outputVariable.

Thanks a lot.

fnery

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an example of what you can do. There are a ton of things you can do to make this work with the functionality you want. Typically I don't like to have any variables in the whole function's workspace besides the inputs and outputs as well as the guihandles. I use `setappdata` and `getappdata` to store other variables and have them accessible to callbacks. This is up to you, but the following is an example of how you can make your simple gui work. The `CloseRequestFcn` allows you the handle what happens if the user just closes the gui. Hope this helps. In addition, the `waitfor` prevents the function from returning until the function is closed. If you want, you can also set the figure's `'WindowStyle'` property to `'modal'` to force the user to put an input before he can close the gui.

```
function outputVariable = exampleGUI(inputVariable) 

    % Any variables declared here will be accessible to the callbacks
    % Initialize output
    outputVariable = [];

    % Initialize newVariable
    newVariable = [];

    % Initialize main figure
    hdl.mainfig = figure('CloseRequestFcn',@closefunction);

    % Add Button
    hdl.addPushButton = uicontrol(hdl.mainfig, 'Units', 'normalized', 'Position',[0.05 0.6 0.3 0.25], 'String', 'Add One', 'Callback', @addOne);
    % Done Button
    hdl.donePushButton = uicontrol(hdl.mainfig, 'Units', 'normalized', 'Position',[0.65 0.6 0.3 0.25], 'String', 'Done', 'Callback', @done);
    % Static text
    hdl.sliceNoText = uicontrol(hdl.mainfig,'Style','text','Fontsize',16,'Units','normalized','Position',[0.35 0.2 0.3 0.25]);


    function addOne(hObject,eventdata) 
        inputVariable = inputVariable+1; % add one to the current inputVariable
        set(hdl.sliceNoText, 'String', num2str(inputVariable)); % change static text
        newVariable = inputVariable; % new variable to be exported
    end

    function closefunction(hObject,eventdata) 
        % This callback is executed if the user closes the gui
        % Assign Output
        outputVariable = newVariable;
        % Close figure
        delete(hdl.mainfig); % close GUI
    end

    function done(hObject,eventdata)  
        % Assign Output
        outputVariable = newVariable;
        % Close figure
        delete(hdl.mainfig); % close GUI
    end

    % Pause until figure is closed ---------------------------------------%
    waitfor(hdl.mainfig);    
end
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @jucestain 
On a side note, are the variables `outputVariable` and `newVariable` considered **global** variables? I have been reading that it is a good practice to avoid global variables, but I can't seem to understand how can we avoid their use in programmatic GUIs using nested functions... Any thoughts on this? (Assuming that the variables I'm referring to are indeed global variables)

Comment: No, they are not global. Their scope is just over the entire function. That means any callback within `exampleGUI()` can access them. Once the function returns they're destroyed. Also, don't forget to accept the answer :)